# My account is still stuck as internal tester. Google Play Console

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-developers-console

There's this message showing in play store - `You're an internal tester. This app may be insecure or unstable.`

I've already leave the beta test program, already paused the track, and already deleted the tester where my email is included. I don't know what still left to do, but the message is still showing.

Does it take a day or week to be updated?

Answer (score 0):

from Google play App go to `Settings` > `General` and turn off `Internal app sharing`

[image: screenshot]